# JavaScript: Referencing a control from another form

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

My displaycloud.aspx page contains two databound data lists, each for displaying a tag cloud. The datalists have an EmptyDataTemplate that holds an empty label if nothing is retrieved from the db. I am trying to display the message 'Please Log a Story', by using the code below on the companyadmin page, but I am getting an error (the controls are not on the same page). How can I reference the labels positive_tags and negative_tags from displaycloud.aspx in companyadmin.aspx? Also, I want to redirect if the EmptyDataTemplate is not executed as shown at the very bottom of the page. Many thanks in advance for your help!

displaycloud.aspx:

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="positive_tags" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</EmptyDataTemplate>

<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="negative_tags" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

companyadmin.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {

    var negative_tags = document.getElementById('negative_tags').innerText;
    var positive_tags = document.getElementById('positive_tags').innerText;

    if (negative_tags == "" && positive_tags == "") {
        (function($) {
            $.jGrowl("Please Log a Story", { theme: 'smoke', closer: true })
            return false;

        })(jQuery);

        return true;
    }

}
</script>
```

Further down ASP page:

```
<asp:Button ID="LinkButtonTagCloud" runat="server" Text="TAG CLOUD" onClientClick="javascript:return validate();" PostBackUrl='<%# string.Format("~/displaycloud.aspx?project={0}&id={1}", Eval("ProjectName"), Eval("ProjectID")) %>' />
```

Comment: Are you saying that javascript running on Page1 should access elements present on Page 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var negative_tags;
    var positive_tags;

    jQuery.ajax({
         url: 'displaycloud.aspx',
         success: function(response, status, xhr) {
           if (status != "error") {
             positive_tags = $('#positive_tags', response).text();
             negative_tags = $('#negative_tags', response).text();
         }},
         async: false
    });         

    alert("Positive tags: " + positive_tags);
    alert("Negative tags: " + negative_tags);

</script>
```

I however recommend you to get this data in **raw format** (JSON by Ajax) directly from the server, for performance and application design reasons:

1. The method above loads the whole `displaycloud.aspx` page in memory before parsing it, which is a useless overhead.
2. In general, from the engineering point of view, you should consider to define different application layers: presentation, business logic and data, raw data sources etc. In your particular case, you should not make one page content dependant on another page content (which is basically making a part of your presentation layer dependant on another part). The data you want to retrieve obviously belongs to the business layer.